# Cannot assign reference value to result of std::invoke

Tags: c++, lambda, rvalue, lvalue

I have a lambda that either appends an object and returns it or it returns an already existing object. On GCC, i receive the error:

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'T&' to an rvalue of type 'T'

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>

struct foo {
    int a;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<foo> foos = {foo{22}};
    std::size_t new_index = -1;
    bool append = (rand() & 1) == 1;
    //compiler error in next line
    foo& new_foo = std::invoke([&foos,&new_index,append](){
        if(append) {
            new_index = foos.size();
            return foos.emplace_back();
        }else {
            new_index = 0;
            return foos[new_index];
        }
    });
    return new_foo.a;
}
```

In this example `new_foo` is supposed to be mutated after retrieving the object, hence `const foo& new_foo` is not an option.

Comment: `[&foos,&new_index,append]()-> foo& { /*..*/ }`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Any possibility without the trailing return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return type of lambda is not a reference by default, you have to specify it with trailling return type( `-> foo&`, `-> decltype(auto)`):

```
[&foos, &new_index, append]()-> foo& { /*..*/ }
```

or return a type which handles reference (as `std::reference_wrapper`):

```
[&foos,&new_index,append]() {
    if(append) {
        new_index = foos.size();
        return std::ref(foos.emplace_back());
    } else {
        new_index = 0;
        return std::ref(foos[new_index]);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qc4M5oM5j)

Comment: returning `std::ref()` makes the compiler complain that `std::reference_wrapper<>` does not contain members of `foo` :/

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qc4M5oM5j) just added for `reference_wrapper`. no errors. Can you share your issue?

Comment: I was using `auto& new_foo = ...`

Comment: Add a `.get()`: `auto& new_foo = std::invoke(/*...*/).get();` to retrieve the reference from the wrapper.